# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException Parameter is not valid

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been getting an odd error with a vb.net application.

> SCRIPT5022:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Parameter is not valid. 
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=xBirR-IOdGGprkqqNevBcHNIkg0D9itajcnT1rzcsTyAeE9pA5bY-Q8F17gzSkJgjYXkLU9Zbo7kEH8CDSE0UEO-xjFfRJDlEGT7xxk-ALz_6yQvfBnU6At9OjGneWCJwyv82OLWiAo5VT7ywYXkDg2&t=ffffffffbd2983fc,
>   line 938 character 13

The error occurs when I upload an image, and with iis (either on my server or locally) and only with image files over 1kb (just happen to have started testing with small files).

The error does not happen when I'm developing the application with visual studio.

I'm using an AsyncFileUpload to upload the file as shown:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="PictureUpload" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Traditional"
ThrobberID="spinner" PersistFile="true" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadStart"  />
```

I get this error message in the body of the ajax response. and I have pinned down the source to a few lines in my code behind where I try to save the file's stream as an image.

> 23|error|500|Parameter is not
>   valid.|

These are the methods I've tried to use.

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
```

or

```
Dim sourceImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(PictureUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
```

or

```
            Dim strm As System.IO.Stream = PictureUpload.PostedFile.InputStream
            Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream()
            Dim buffer(2048) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = 1
            While (bytesRead <> 0)
                bytesRead = strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            End While

            Dim sourceImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream)
```

I'm guessing since small images are working it's a limitation Somewhere in either IIS or my web.config.

so I tried adding.

```
<httpRuntime
  maxRequestLength="1048576"
  executionTimeout="3600"
/>
<sessionState
  timeout="60"
/>
```

To web.config... and IIS seems to be configured as default to accept files up to 4MB.

Does anybody have any thoughts as to what I might have missed? Or how to chunk the input stream somehow?

The html source does have.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

In the form tag.

I've Googled much for this, and none of the advice I found seems to work.

Thanks for your time in advance :)

-Paul.

:: I've also tried adding ::

```
PictureUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

and

```
PictureUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Position = 0
```

Comment: What's the error message? You mention it but don't tell us what it says. EDIT: Never mind, I just saw it's the title ... that was very easy to miss.  You may want to put the full error in your post anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tony, you're right. I've attempted to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Did you easily try to save the file using the AsyncFileUploade.SaveFile method?